# Use method of parent class when extending

Tags: php

Probably a silly question.. but how do I correctly use the methods of class Test in class Testb without overriding them?

```
<?php
class Test {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

<?php

class Testb extends Test {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

}

<?php

include('test.php');
include('testb.php');

$a = new Test('John');
$b = new Testb('Batman');

echo $b->getName();
```

Comment: What is the current output that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `Testb` constructor a `$name` parameter too if you want to be able to initialize it with that argument. I modified your `Testb` class so that its constructor actually takes an argument. The way you currently have it, you should not be able to initialize your `Testb` class. I use the code as follows:

```
<?php
class Test {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

class Testb extends Test {

    // I added the $name parameter to this constructor as well
    // before it was blank.
    public function __construct($name) {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

}

$a = new Test('John');
$b = new Testb('Batman');

echo $a->getName();
echo $b->getName();
?>
```

Perhaps you do not have error reporting enabled? In any event, you can verify my results here: http://ideone.com/MHP2oX

Comment: Aahh That was the part I Missed I did not add the argument in my child class when calling the parent constructor :) thanks!